# How can i use xcode 14.3.1 under Sonoma 14?

Tags: xcode

How can i use xcode14.3.1 under Sonoma 14? When i use xcode15, my project will load with no response usually, and there are some error will not appear in xcode14，like "no platform load command found in assuming: iOS"

Can anyone tell me what to do

Comment: You will need to show more information I think. There is very purely info here. Have you downloaded the iOS 17 simulators?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already installed iOS 17 simulators. When i ues xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d), i got error like: ld: 54 duplicate symbols ld:1:1: no platform load command found in '```.o)', assuming: iOS clang:1:1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) .But it didn't happen in 14.3.1. So i want to use xcode14.3.1 under Sonoma 14 to run my project, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: As much as you think that that would solve the problem it won’t. Xcode 14 is not compatible with Sonoma. But we can try to solve the actual problem you are having instead. That will mean your project works with Xcode 15.

Answer (score -2):

On this specific topic, Apple's documentation is not very clear:

> Xcode 14.3.1 requires a Mac running macOS Ventura 13.0 or later.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3_1-release-notes

In the past, the noted have been a little more clear:

> Xcode 13.4.1 requires a Mac running macOS Monterey 12. (Note: macOS Ventura 13 only supports Xcode 14 beta.)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_4_1-release-notes

You could try installing Xcode 14.3.1 via download, and giving it a different name. This isn't without minor risks in very complicated setups, but if you can't build, it may be worth a try.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i have already installed xcode14.3.1 according to this post, it can solve my problem: [Sonoma 14 & Xcode 14.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734709?login=true)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest trying any hacky way to fix this. Apple says it's incompatible for a reason. I would focus on fixing the issue to make your project compatible with XCode 15. It'll save you time and headaches in the long run.

Comment: Not sure, but your solution, "You could try installing Xcode 14.3.1 via download, and giving it a different name." wasn't from your source.

Comment: Yeah. That part was my opinion. I haven't found Apple documentation on having multiple copies of Xcode (some of their sites recommend using App Store...) but most developers I know have more than once version installed. The CLI tools seem to support it, but Xcode is so complex and the usage is so varied, so I think it was sound advice with the proper disclaimer.